# creating symbolic link

Tags: symbolic-link

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gZCk.png) I was trying to create a symbolic link named `lsfic6` in `test` directory of the file `fic6` located in `test/rep1/rep4/`, so I ran:

```
ln -s test/rep1/rep4/fic6 /home/user/test/lsfic6
```

I see that the link was created, but it's colored in red and it was pointing to `test/rep1/re4/fic6`, as though pointing to an nonexistent file. Why is that?

Comment: What directory did you run the `ln` command from? What is the output of `ls -l /home/user/lsfic6` (please [edit] that into your question, don't put it in a coment)?

Comment: from my personel directory

Comment: Please answer both questions: what is the output of `ls -l /home/user/lsfic6`. Also, where is `test/rep1/rep4/fic6`? If you `cd` into it, what does `pwd` tell you?

Comment: 1) lsfic6 is in test/                                                                                                                             2)    test/rep1/rep4/fic6 is in home/user/  . so if I pwd it gives :/home/user/test/rep1/rep4/

Comment: Please ***EDIT*** the question and add the new details, do not put them in comments. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss, and can be deleted without warning. Now, if `lsfic6` is in `test`, that means it is `/home/user/test/lsfic6`, so why are you showing `/home/user/lsfic6` instead?

Comment: Wait, did you mean to run `ln -s test/rep1/rep4/lsfic6 /home/user/lsfic6`? Did you just forget to add `ls` and just used `fic6` by mistake?

Comment: sorry lsfic6 is in /home/user/test/  and not in /home/user/ .

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you used a relative path. You ran this:

```
ln -s test/rep1/rep4/fic6 /home/user/lsfic6
```

This means "create a link at `/home/user/lsfic6` pointing to `test/rep1/rep4/fic6`". Since the target starts with `test`, not a `/`, this is a relative path. In other words, `test/` means "a directory named `test` that is a sub directory of my current directory".

Think of absolute paths like house addresses (e.g. "14, Bat Street, Gotham City") and relative paths like directions to get to there from here (e.g. "Walk down this street, take the second left and you will be there"). The relative paths depend on where you are, while the absolute paths do not.

So, if this `test/` directory is `/home/user/test`, then your command would work, but if `test/` is not in `/home/user/test`, the link will be broken, as you saw.

This might be clearer with an example. Consider this:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo
$ ls -lA
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Mar 28 13:42 test
```

I have a directory named `/home/terdon/foo` and, in that directory, I have a sub-directory named `test`. So, the full path to `test` is `/home/terdon/foo/test`. And, when I am in `/home/terdon/foo`, the *relative* path to `test` is just `test` or `./test` since it is in the same directory where I am.

Now, if I make a symlink to `test`, it works:

```
$ ln -s test link
$ ls -lA
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    4 Mar 28 13:46 link -> test
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Mar 28 13:42 test
```

If I try the same thing in another directory, however, I will get a broken link:

```
$ cd /home/terdon
$ ln -s test link
$ ls -l link
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 4 Mar 28 13:47 link -> test
```

In the second example, the link is broken and would appear red:

[image: screenshot showing the result of the above commands in the terminal]

So, either use absolute paths (e.g. `ln -s /some/dir/test/rep1/rep4/fic6 /home/user/lsfic6`) or make sure to run the `ln` command from the correct directory so that the relative path works (e.g. `cd /some/dir` and then `ln -s test/rep1/rep4/fic6 /home/user/lsfic6`).

Comment: that's right . when I gave the absolute path it works ! thanks fir helping .